# I can't debug cordova app with chrome inspect anymore

Tags: cordova, debugging, phonegap-plugins, google-chrome-devtools, inspect

I don't know why, but suddenly when I try to debug a cordova app with chrome://inspect/devices, as I've been doing so far, I just can see the device name but not the `index.html` from the app.

What am I missing?

This is what I get now:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. Just had to change in `platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml`; `android:debuggable="false"` to `android:debuggable="true"`.